# How to create a double-side printable report?

Tags: double-sided, report

I am using this code (`\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}`) to make my thesis able to print in double-side. I assume it should create some blank pages to have the chapters always in the right. But it doesn't. Any idea please?

Comment: Left chapters? Do you mean that chapter can begin on a verso page?

Comment: Yes, like those we have in books

Comment: Normally chapters do start on a right-handed  page, i.e. recto (odd page numbers), at least with left-to-right fonts. Try the `openany` option in addition to `12pt` etc.

Comment: I tried, but no changes.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\blindtext[10]

\chapter{Second}

\end{document}`  -- This will open chapters on left page

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by \documentclass[12pt,openright, twoside]{report}.

Comment: `openright` opens chapters on the right page, that's why it's called `openright` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

```
 \documentclass[12pt,openright, twoside]{report}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer?

Comment: add `\usepackage[right=3.5in,showframe]{geometry}` to check which pages are left and which are right.

Comment: Adding this option: openright will create blank pages, so that the beginning of the chapter is always on the roight.